# plotly tree map error: ValueError: Value of 'path_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'

Tags: pandas, plotly

I'm new to plotly and trying to plot a tree map but received an error: `ValueError: Value of 'path_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['country_name', 'counts'] but received: c`

Example data

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
d = {'country_name':['USA', 'UK', 'Germany'], 'counts':[100, 200, 300]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Plot

```
fig = px.treemap(dd, path='country_name', values='counts')
fig.show()
```

Not sure why I received this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a treemap, you need to set the paths as a list as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
d = {'country_name':['USA', 'UK', 'Germany'], 'counts':[100, 200, 300]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.treemap(dd, path=['country_name'], values='counts')
fig.show()
```